# Is it possible to remove edit history?

Tags: support, edits, revision-history

I accidentally included some not-so-good data in a copy-paste into my post. I've edited the post to remove the data, but I'm wondering if I can remove "the edit itself" so it's not possible to dig into the revision history and view the data.

Is it?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276380

Comment: No, but you can flag a moderator requesting an SO dev to do so.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, how exactly do I do that? I mean, flagging a particular revision of a question?

Comment: @KlaymenDK Just flag your question, select "In need of moderator intervention" and explain which specific revision you want removed and why.

Comment: But note that the point of this revision redaction is to remove really problematic issues (e.g. passwords, personally identifying information, etc.), not to remove a few typos from history. (It's not clear from your history which of the two is the case).